# Insert values to mysql table via Java GUI

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I'm working with java and mysql and I'm facing a problem. I'm trying to create an app with GUI to insert data into mysql table and this is the code :

```
public void insertuser(String fullname,String salary,String adress,String username,String password) throws SQLException
{
    openconnection();
    //openconnection method works well
    String queryInsert =
         "INSERT INTO hema.employee (Emp_name,Emp_salary,Adress,UserName,PassWord)"
       + "VALUES ('"+fullname+"','"+salary+"','"+adress+"','"+username+"','"+password+"')";
    Statement stm=(Statement) con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    stm.executeQuery(queryInsert);
}
```

and in the JFrame  class I call this method using this code :

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        String NAME   =jTextField1.getText();
        String SALARY =jTextField2.getText() ;
        String ADRESS =jTextField3.getText();
        String USER   =jTextField4.getText();
        String PASS   =jPasswordField1.getText();

        Employee emp=new Employee();
        emp.insertuser(NAME, SALARY, ADRESS, USER, PASS);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }       
}
```

and the first error I have is:

`java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `executeQuery()` method is only for executing select statements.  For insert, update, and delete statements, you should use the [`executeUpdate()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-).

> Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
String sqlInsert =
     "INSERT INTO hema.employee (Emp_name,Emp_salary,Adress,UserName,PassWord)"
     + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
try (PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(sqlInsert)) {
    stm.setString(1, fullname);
    stm-setBigDecimal(2, new BigDecimal(salary));
    stm.setString(3, adress);
    stm.setString(4, username);
    stm.setString(5, password);
    int updateCount = stm.executeUpdate(); // 1 when inserted 1 record
} // Closes stm
```

The error, that for INSERT, DELETE. UPDATE and such `executeUpdate` should be used is given already.

Also close the statement, for example use the above try-with-resources.

Important is to use a prepared statement. This is a security measure (against [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)), but also escapes quotes and backslashes in the values

Another advantage of a prepared statement is that you could reuse it; not so necessary here.

But more important is the type safe setting of fields: I altered the salary field to use BigDecimal, appropriate for numeric values with decimals (SQL column type DECIMAL or so).